# Problems using lifetimes in structs in Rust

Tags: rust, struct, lifetime

I have this test rust code and I am having problems with the use of lifetimes and I don't know what is happening (For this test I need the "my" element of the Xd struct to be a reference), this is the code:

```
struct Xd<'a> {
    mi: &'a String,
}

impl<'a> Xd<'a> {
    pub fn new(mi: &'a String) -> Self {
        Self {
            mi,
        }
    }
}

struct Hola<'a> {
    mi: String,
    xd: Xd<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Hola<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let mi = String::from("f");
        let xd = Xd::new(&mi);

        Self {
            mi,
            xd,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let hola = Hola::new();
    println!("Hola mi: {}", hola.mi);
}
```

And these are the errors I'm getting:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `mi`
  --> src\main.rs:23:9
```

y

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `mi` because it is borrowed
  --> src\main.rs:24:13
```

I hope someone could help me solve this error, thank you